# Exclusion of "lib" prefix in flags for gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Guys gave me their library: `libA.a` and `libB.a`. Also, I have header files: `header_A.h` and `header_B.h`. I need to add them to my `Makefile`. I've added this:

```
INCLUDES = -I/home/me/lib_from_guys/include
LIBS = -L/home/me/lib_from_guys/libraries
CFLAGS = -llibA -llibB

hello:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

BUT! compiler said, that it could not find `libA` and `libB`. I've changed on this:

```
CFLAGS = -lA -lB
```

And now it works. Is it necessary always supress `"lib"` prefix in lib? Or how it knows names of my libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a standard behavior in C for many, many years.

The `-lX` option will automatically prompt the linker to look for something named `libX`, not `X`.  So, yes, you always exclude the `lib` portion of the name to `-l`.